# Custom Checkable View which responds to Selector

Tags: android, view, custom-view

I have a group of `FrameLayout` which I want to be checkable/selectable,

That is, after a click I would like the `FrameLayout` to display as `checked` - when pressed again I would like it to become un`checked`. What's more, I want this visual que to be described as usual through though the use of a `<selector>`.

I can't seem to get this working - I'm not sure what I'm missing:

```
public class CheckableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked = false;
    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }
}
```

The layout of the `CheckableFrameLayout`:

```
<com.test.view.CheckableFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true" >
```

The selector backing it (selector_horizontal.xml):

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_vertical_selected" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_checked="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_vertical_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_vertical_normal" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_checked="false"/>
```

Using the above code the "state_pressed" is working fine, but the View itself is not becoming checked (not is the `Checkable` code being called as discovered through debug).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding the following code to a `Checkable` class allows Selectors to work:

```
private static final int[] CheckedStateSet = {
    android.R.attr.state_checked,
};

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (isChecked()) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CheckedStateSet);
    }
    return drawableState;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();
    return super.performClick();
}
```

Comment: `onCreateDrawableState` doesn't called from LinearLayout by some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Comment: This doesn't support initial cheked state `android:checked="true"`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete working example for a CheckableButton. It also works on Android 4.2.

```
public class CheckableButton extends Button implements Checkable {

    private static final int[] CheckedStateSet = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    private boolean mChecked = false;

    public CheckableButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CheckableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        mChecked = !mChecked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CheckedStateSet);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `performClick()` method, look at accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:state_activated`.

```
<item android:drawable="@color/HighlightColor"      android:state_activated="true"/>
```

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android%3astate_activated):

> State value for StateListDrawable, set when a view or its parent has
>   been "activated" meaning the user has currently marked it as being of
>   interest.

Comment: Where should I put that tag? It's not available for `<item>`.

Comment: It's just like any other state.  I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: `state_activated` makes no difference at all (It's also API 11)

Comment: I think we missed the obvious... `android:checkable="true"`.  Try that in the layout.  Then again maybe not, the only place I see that mentioned is for building menus... although I suppose it wouldn't hurt to try it anyway.

Comment: Umm, where?  You have `android:clickable`, not `android:checkable`.

Comment: Ah, I see, misread - `android:checkable` isn't available for a `FrameLayout`

Comment: Well, bugger.  I'm out of ideas. You wouldn't think it would be so difficult.

Comment: Nope, I've fixed it now, check out the other answer. I know it's bad form but I don't know why the `Drawable` state doesn't include state_checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering tags in your `selector_horizontal.xml` These are evaluated top to bottom. It seems that in your case either `android:state_pressed="false" or android:state_pressed="true"` is applied and evaluation never reaches third line with `android:state_checked="true"` Try moving first line to last:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/HighlightColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/selected_color" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

Comment: Makes no difference - I made sure each item was implicit (contains both state_pressed and state_checked) so that they won't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Graeme's answer above
do the following modification to toggle()

```
@Override
public void toggle() {
    mChecked = !mChecked;
    refreshDrawableState();
}
```

Comment: I've included this in the original answer

Comment: the only addition here is we need to call refreshDrawableState() in toggle() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Graeme's solution doesn't worked from me under Android 4.0.3 (and I suppose it won't work under 4.0 too). Instead you can change `state_checked` to `state_activated`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/activated_image" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/not_activated_image" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_activated="false"/>

</selector>
```

and use `setActivated` inside your `setChecked`:

```
@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    mChecked = checked;
    setActivated(checked);
}
```

and that is all. Implementing `onCreateDrawableState` isn't required here.

Comment: See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android%3astate_activated) - "This is an alternative representation of state_checked for when the state should be propagated down the view hierarchy.", Sound's like this is only useful if you also want the children of your view to respond `true` if their parent is checked.

Comment: Graeme's solution works for me for a checkable Button (I also added refreshDrawableState() to setChecked() and toggle() as suggested by sujith.