# Explanation of state_activated, state_selected, state_pressed, state_focused for ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Can anyone explain (or point me to a link that explains) the difference between state_activated, state_selected, state_pressed, and state_focused for ListView items? Are they all valid states for ListViews? Does it matter if touch or a keyboard are being used? [This link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html) no longer seems to be valid.

Many thanks!

Comment: The new link is here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

- `state_selected` is used when an item is selected using a
  keyboard/dpad/trackball/etc.
- `state_activated` is used when View.setActivated(true) is called. This
  is used for "persistent selection" (see Settings on tablet for
  instance)
- `state_pressed` is used when the user is pressing the item either
  through touch or a keyboard or a mouse
- `state_focused` is used if the item is marked focusable and it receives
  focus either through the user of a keyboard/dpad/trackball/etc. or if
  the item is focusable in touch mode

Comment: difference between state_activated and state_active ?

Comment: Does "state_activated" get used on other cases? for example, what is used when making a multiple-selection on a listView ? What is the difference between using "state_activated" and "state_checked" ?

Comment: I was wondering, I am going to be using activated for highlighting one item in a list view, but does it set the activate for other list items to false ... if not do either of these do that so I do not have to find the other activated child item and set activation to false?