# Selected state for ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have image Button like below.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 

        android:background="@drawable/perm_group_calendar"/>
```

perm_group_calendar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/perm_group_calendar_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/perm_group_calendar_normal" />    
</selector>
```

The selected state is not working by itself. I found answer from this SO

[Android ImageButton with a selected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state)

I used the below code. now  it works.

```
 imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View button) {
               if (button.isSelected()){
                   button.setSelected(false); 
                   //...Handle toggle off
               } else {
                   button.setSelected(true);
                   //...Handled toggle on
               }
           }

       });
```

Why We have to toggle the selected state ?

Comment: You would have to use a `ToggleButton` for that, with the `checked` property.

Comment: imageButton.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.perm_group_calendar)); try this

Comment: @RajeshCP Even if i use the setImageDrawable in my code , I have to set the selected state by myself using the oncliklistener, then only it works.

Comment: yeah you set the drawable like this, and rest remains the same. Inside your click listener button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the **selected** state isn't automatically shown by an ImageButton, which - normally (as opposed to artificially) - shows only the **normal** and **pressed** statuses (not sure about the **focused** state, but it should).

You could else use a **custom** ToggleButton (or a Switch or a CheckBox).

Anyway, your solution doesn't look that bad at all, to me.

Comment: yeah . I can understand, so the selected state wont work automattically. we should do it ourself. is this the design issue from   android development team.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an issue. It's by design. Good that we can overcome such "limitations" in an easy way... ;)

Answer (score 2):

i think you should do some thing as the following in your drawable XML file  :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/aaaa" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/aaaa"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />    
</selector>
```

and your ImageButton like the following :

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/drawableFile" />
```

you should add the android:state_pressed="true" , and that should do the trick for the pressed state .

as RomianGuy mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13634298/957654) :

state_selected is used when an item is selected using a keyboard/dpad/trackball/etc .
so i think thats why you have to toggle the state .

Hope That Helps .

Comment: It is not working. Pressed state is working . Selected state is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. If you want to change icon AND color for ImageButton - you need 2 selectors - for 'android:src' and for 'android:src' :

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibToFavorites"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_checkin_to_favourite"
            android:tint="@color/selector_checkin_to_favourite"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
```

res/drawable/selector_checkin_to_favourite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected = "true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_black_45dp"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_45dp"/>
</selector>
```

res/color/selector_checkin_to_favourite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected = "true"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item
        android:color="@color/colorSecondary"/>
</selector>
```