# ListView TextColor change

Tags: android, android-listview

I have Listview. I want the color of the text that I have selected to change to white once i have selected it, and to stay white, however when i select another item in the listview I want the previously selected item's color to revert to the default black and the newly selected item to change to white.

My color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

This only turns the textcolor to white on if i keep the item pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **state_activated** for this, you're really only handling press events in your selector, which is a transient condition that becomes false as soon as the user removes their finger.

You may alternatively be looking for **state_selected**, review [Explanation of state_activated, state_selected, state_pressed, state_focused for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634259/explanation-of-state-activated-state-selected-state-pressed-state-focused-for) for more information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    .
    .
    .
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />

    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```