# Toggle Buttons usage

Tags: android, togglebutton

What is the difference in doing the following using Toggle buttons?

```
togglebut.isChecked();
togglebut.isSelected();
```

and similarly `setSelected()` and `setChecked()`.

-EDIT-
The question has now been answered as a community wiki and includes the `Activated` case too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504860/what-is-the-difference-between-the-states-selected-checked-and-activated-in-and ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't referred to the docs before asking this question. The doc actually makes it clear. I am answering this so that anyone who gets to this question actually gets a ***meaningful*** answer. According to the doc.

**android:state_selected Boolean**. "true" if this item should be used when the object is the current user selection when navigating with a directional control (such as when navigating through a list with a d-pad); "false" if this item should be used when the object is not selected. The selected state is used when focus (android:state_focused) is not sufficient (such as when list view has focus and an item within it is selected with a d-pad).

**android:state_checked Boolean**. "true" if this item should be used when the object is checked; "false" if it should be used when the object is un-checked.

**android:state_activated Boolean**. "true" if this item should be used when the object is activated as the persistent selection (such as to "highlight" the previously selected list item in a persistent navigation view); "false" if it should be used when the object is not activated. Introduced in API level 11.

For further details refer to the link posted in the comment above. It elaborates on this.