# Highlight Multiple Selected/Checked/Activated in ListView

Tags: java, android

Wow, documentation is horrible when it comes to list item selection. All I need is to be able to select and highlight multiple items in a list. I've scoured the web and seen references to [`android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode), which I'm guessing allows you to select multiple items. But where can I get the selected items in my Activity? And how come when I try to select multiple items using `setSelection(position)`, the previously highlighted item disappears?

Google also describes in [`View.setActivated(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated(boolean)) that

> Note that activation is not the same as selection. Selection is a transient property, representing the view (hierarchy) the user is currently interacting with. Activation is a longer-term state that the user can move views in and out of. For example, in a list view with single or multiple selection enabled, the views in the current selection set are activated. (Um, yeah, we are deeply sorry about the terminology here.)

So am I supposed to use activation instead of selection? [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261981/1852456) talks about how "activated" is just the post-HoneyComb version of "checked". But if you're supposed to use "activated" for multiple selection, whats the point of `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So apparently I was led off the wrong track because I was supposed to be looking for highlighting "checked" items and not "selected" items. Thus, many answers told me to use the `selector` with my ListView layout using `android:listSelector="@drawable/myselector`, but what I really needed was to use the `selector` with my row layout. The solution is actually rather simple, I'll post it below:

**drawable/rowbackgroundselector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
</selector>
```

- note how you use "state_activated" to detect if an item is "checked"...

**drawable/mylistrow.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rowbackgroundselector"
    android:padding="10sp"
/>
```

- using the selector for the row background

**MainActivity.onListItemClick()**

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    getListView().setItemChecked(pos, true);
}
```

Lastly, make sure your adapter is using your custom row layout

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FileTag>(this.getActivity(),
    R.layout.mylistrow, mList);
```

Comment: I know this is mad old, but I just found it and it solved an issue I've been working on for two days (amateur). I want to add that you still have to use (your_listview_name).setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE). This can be either in the listItemClick() or setOnItemLongClickListener. I had a similar question which, using this answer, I have found the solution to. Thanks! Here's my answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287947/5374362